# Не ставится grub на логический раздел

Tags: linux, файловая-система, grub, archlinux

Если grub возможно установить только на физический диск, скажите об этом сразу с ссылкой доказывающей это, я отмечу это как ответ, дальше читать мой вопрос бессмысленно.

Если же это не так, то помогите установить этот загрузчик.
Размечаю диск в GPT, создаю 3 раздела через cfdisk:

- 300Mb `/boot`
- 20Gb `/`
- 30Gb `/mySpace`

Первый форматирую `mkfs.vfat`, остальные `mkfs.ext4`
Ставлю арч, после чрута пытаюсь установить grub в `/dev/sda1` (300Mb), но граб начинает ругаться

> warning: File system 'fat' doesn't support embedding.
>
> warning: Embedding is not possible. GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists. However, blocklists are UNREALIABLE and their use is discouraged...
>
> error: will not proceed with blocklists.

Разумеется я пробовал с другими ФС, ничего не меняется.

Подозреваю что либо эта проблема возникает только на GPT, либо GRUB можно ставить только на физические диски `/dev/sdX`. Сейчас я попробую с MBR.

Кстати, если граб можно ставить на логические диски, то я правильно понимаю что такая установка более надежна чем запись в специальный раздел физического диска?

**p.s.** пожалуйста, будьте объективны и не пишите здесь о том, что GPT отстой и мне обязательно нужно сменить разметку

Comment: BIOS или UEFI ?

Comment: @KoVadim `BIOS`

Comment: так будет сложно завести. Нужно переключатся на uefi (но лучше выбрать режим "not secured" (или как оно там будет называться))

Comment: @KoVadim но могу сменить на UEFI если нужно (VMBox)

Comment: @KoVadim я пробовал устанавливать из-под BIOS, первый (загрузочный) раздел помечал как загрузочный UEFI, ставил граб через `--force`, выключал машину, менял BIOS на UEFI и пытался загрузиться, но это никакого результата не принесло. Выполнял и `grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot --bootloader-id=grub` - ничего не менялось

Comment: Кстати, в режиме UEFI я не могу открыть LiveCD. Меню появляется, но вечная загрузка при выборе "установить"

Comment: конечно оно не даст результата. Нужно все ставить в uefi режиме.  Есть лайфхак - можно поставить вначале убунту или федору, что бы они "правильно разметили", а потом "подсмотреть".

Comment: Если у меня не останется выбора - в конечном счете я попробую это. Но в этом будет не очень много смысла даже если все получится. Очень хочу поставить систему именно так, что бы получить опыт. Из спортивного интереса. Если я правильно понимаю, такой способ более надежен, чем установка загрузчика в загрузочную запись

Comment: есть два способа - биос (старый) и uefi - новый. В старом нужно в загрузочную область записать 512 байт груба, в новом - нужно просто создать специальный раздел, куда добавить нужные файлы grub (к примеру, grubx64.efi). и тип ESP. UEFI сам найдет такой раздел и загрузчик на нем (загрузчиков может быть много). А отдельный дистрибутив я рекомендую поставить, что бы посмотреть, как оно все настроится. Потом его можно снести и ставить ручками. И конечно, перечитайте ещё раз документацию - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9) она там хорошая

Comment: Разобрался с запуском liveCD через efi, думаю теперь всё будет в порядке и у меня все получится

Comment: процесс загрузки коротко и дельно описан в [вики-статье](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB#Version_2_(GRUB)). судя по приведённому вами тексту сообщения, если на блочном устройстве (а раздел — это тоже «блочное устройство в миниатюре») наличествует файловая система *fat*, то *grub* не может нормально разместить и адресовать на этом блочном устройстве содержимое stage1.5 и/или файлы stage2. а с размещением stage1 точно проблем быть не может: к нему ведь адресоваться не нужно.

Comment: что-то развели вы тут с UEFI кашу... grub 2 легко устанавливается в раздел — достаточно только добавить `--force`, но целесообразность такой установки и возможные проблемы предмет отдельной дискуссии...

Comment: @Fat-Zer чушь. Сейчас в efi режиме без проблем установил всё как хотел. Как вы себе представляете механизм поиска загрузчика BIOS'ом? Он достаточно примитивен и как я понял, просто сканирует первые 2048Кб данных жесткого диска в поисках загрузчика. Если находит - передает управление ему, иначе говорит о том, что загрузчик системы не найден

Comment: @Петр, без другого загрузчика в mbr — ни как... я же говорю, целесообразность этого — отдельный вопрос... я представляю себе только один вариант, когда это может понадобится (и когда я это использовал): установка win и linux на один диск, когда в mbr ставится виндовый загрузчик и уже из него грузится grub (подразумевая, что задача построить именно такую систему)...

Comment: @Fat-Zer а как в этой ситуации загрузчик винды обнаруживает grub? Просто интересен механизм.

Comment: @Петр, раздел с `grub`'ом просто прописывается строчкой в конфиге... по крайней мере в ХРюшке был простой текстовый конфиг, позволявший передать управление загрузчику на выбранном устройстве аналогично `chainloader`'у `grub`'а... сам grub stage1 устанавливается в VBR, stage1.5 остаётся файлом на диске (но это может неожиданно поломаться, например от дефрагментации или неудачной переустановки пакета с grub'ом о чём он и предупреждает в сообщении вопросе)...

Comment: @KoVadim поставил все как хотел, но сейчас заметил, что после выключения машины - при следующем запуске граб просто не загружается. Это интересно, потому что после установки я перезагрузил машину и все было ок, появилось grub меню и все круто. Но после выключения и включения - ничего. При этом я могу запустить систему из файла через UEFI (Boot From File в Boot Maintenance Manager). В чём дело?